# PHPMailer, Fatal error: Call to a member function Send() on a non-object

Tags: php, phpmailer

I get this error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function Send() on a non-object`. This error concerns the line `if(!$mail->Send())`.

I searched on another forum and it might be about using "load->" somewhere but I'm not sure why and how.

```
function New_Mail($email,$firstname,$surname,$body, $subject, $altBody, $wordwrap){

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port

$mail->Username   = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxxxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->From       = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Admin";

$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->AltBody    =  $altBody;//Text Body
$mail->WordWrap   = $wordwrap; // set word wrap
$mail->AddAddress($email,$firstname." ".$surname);

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddReplyTo("replyto@yourdomain.com","Admin");
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

}

$mail=New_Mail($email,$firstname,$surname,'This is the body','Welcome','this is the alternate body',100);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
// nothing is displayed
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the error because `$mail` at the bottom of your code is not an object. You have this snippet of code:

```
$mail=New_Mail($email,$firstname,$surname,'This is the body','Welcome','this is the alternate body',100);
```

However, `New_Mail()` doesn't actually return anything, so `$mail` is an empty variable.

One way to fix this is to return the `$mail` object in `New_Mail()`.

Another note: be careful when choosing variable names. You're using the varname `$mail` within the `New_Mail()` function and outside of the function. This is perfectly fine, but just remember that the `$mail` object from within `New_Mail()` is no longer in scope by the time you call `Send()`. That's why PHP is throwing up.

Answer (score 1):

show var_dump($mail) before calling $mail->Send(); May be you forgot to include the class? for example `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');`