# PHPMailer Function not included

Tags: php, error-handling

I have this file made by me for PHPMailer(mail.php) :

```
<?php
function Send($to,$subject,$msg,$from){
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->From     = "$from";
$mail->AddAddress("$to");
$mail->Subject  = "$subject";
$mail->Body     = "$msg";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
}
}
if(function_exists("Send")){
    echo "Function is defined";
}
else{
    echo "Function isn't defined";
}

?>
```

And I include it into my contact form handling php file(report.php) :

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2>
    <?php
    $url="http://127.0.0.1/phpmailer/mail.php";
    echo "$url";
    include_once($url);
        $name=$_POST['firstname']." ".$_POST['lastname'];
        $how_many=$_POST['howmany'];
        $what_they_did=$_POST['whattheydid'];
        $other=$_POST['other'];
        $when_it_happened=$_POST['whenithappened'];
        $how_long=$_POST['howlong'];
        $alien_description=$_POST['aliendescription'];
        $fang_spotted=$_POST['fangspotted'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];

        $to="user@mail.com";
        $subject='Aliens Abducted Me - Abduction Report';
        $msg="$name was abducted $when_it_happened and was gone for $how_long.\n".
            "Number of Aliens : $how_many\n".
            "Alien description : $alien_description\n".
            "What they did : $what_they_did\n".
            "Fang spotted : $fang_spotted\n".
            "Other comments : $other";

        Send($to,$subject,$msgm,$mail);   //this is the problematic line

        echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br />';
        echo 'You were abducted '.$when_it_happened.'<br />';
        echo ' and were gone for '.$how_long.'<br />';
        echo "Number of aliens : ".$how_many.'<br />';
        echo "Describe them : ".$alien_description.'<br />';
        echo "The aliens did this : ".$what_they_did.'<br />';
        echo "Was Fang there?".$fang_spotted.'<br />';
        echo "Other comments : ".$other.'<br />';
        echo "Your email address is ".$email;

    ?>
```

This is just an exemple from a book I'm learning PHP from so don't freak out :)))...My problem is that when I submit the form, I always get this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Send() in path/report.php on line 30
```

The error occurs even if function_exists() evaluates to true...Why?

EDIT:

I am working on localhost ant these are the paths to my files :

```
mail.php : localweb\phpmailer\mail.php
report.php : localweb\hf_php\ch01\initial\aliens\report.php
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you working on Localhost?

Comment: it looks similar to this post. try to follow this. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221778/phpmailer-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-send-on-a-non-object[link]

Comment: @nevermind ..Does it matter? Because the file is made by me in that directory.

Comment: @Kishore : I don't use $mail outside my Send function...I also renamed it so it does't conflict with the one in the "if(!$mail->Send()) " and still the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the file directly from the local file system. What you currently have is actually fetching your file over the network, and *including the result of executing the script* which is sent from your webserver.

Given your file structure:

```
mail.php: localweb\phpmailer\mail.php
report.php: localweb\hf_php\ch01\initial\aliens\report.php
```

In `report.php` your include statement should be:

```
include_once("../../../../phpmailer/mail.php");
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about that first comment, I was wrong, upvoted ;)

Comment: In the report.php I get that the function exists, so I'm sure that the file gets included, but why not executed?

Comment: @csanonymus When you [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) a file via the network, what you're doing is including the _result_ of executing that script, not the script itself. It has the same effect as if you opened http://127.0.0.1/phpmailer/mail.php in your web browser, and copy and pasted the result into your script. You see "Function is defined" because that's what the mail.php outputs.

Comment: @PaulFerrett :  I did this : '$url="../../../../phpmailer/mail.php";' and it seems to work..I'm waiting to receive the e-mail to my account and see if it really works :X